# Why does parseFloat accept strange symbols?

Tags: javascript

`parseFloat('10$5')` evaluates to 10.

Why does javascript consider this valid?

Comment: `parseFloat` and `parseInt` are defined to look at the string until they encounter an "invalid" character. That's what the spec says. Not sure what else you want to know about that? From the spec: *"parseFloat may interpret only a leading portion of string as a Number value; it ignores any code units that cannot be interpreted as part of the notation of an decimal literal, and no indication is given that any such code units were ignored."* https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-parsefloat-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> parseFloat parses its argument, a string, and returns a floating point
>   number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -),
>   numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value
>   up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding
>   characters. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Answer (score 1):

Because it stops evaluating as soon as it can no longer parse a number. If you did `parseFloat('$105')` it would evaluate to NaN.

Comment: *evaluate to `NaN`